# Bitcoin - Read transaction details from LevelDB

Tags: bitcoin-core, leveldb

I am new to LevelDB and the way BTC keeps everything in the database. I went through article [How does Bitcoin read from/write to LevelDB](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51387/how-does-bitcoin-read-from-write-to-leveldb) but was not able to get to the first step -

Transaction

```
246c5a81b6ad0dfc0dbc0b2ff5bde65ee1913f75a47d409b8ff8074a27ec1000
```

is identified in the LevelDB by:

```
c0010ec274a07f88f9b407da4753f91e15ee6bdf52f0bbc0dfc0dadb6815a6c24
```

How does the first string translates back to `c0010ec274a07f88f9b407da4753f91e15ee6bdf52f0bbc0dfc0dadb6815a6c24`? I understand the first character is c but what calculation makes the second string?

I am using .Net Core to read level DB using LevelDB.Standard nuget package (Assembly LevelDB.NET, Version=2.1.6.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two strings are the same, but with the bytes (hex digit pairs) in reversed order (with an extra `c` at the beginning).  The first string starts with `24 6c 5a ...` and the second string ends with `... 5a 6c 24`.

It looks like an endianness flip to me (network order is big-endian, but  your machine is presumably using little-endian order).  I don't know what the meaning of the extra `c` is.

Comment: The 'c' simply stands for "coin", FWIW; it distinguishes it from a few meta records in the database that are not UTXOs.